# How to use usbmon for knowing amount of data transferred from usb (pendrive )?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, shell, kernel

Please someone explain me in simple terms how to use usbmon to track the amount  of data transferred from pendrive  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**usbmon.txt**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt) and [**usbmon.txt Examples**](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt#179) gives a clear explanation about usbmon or usbdump.

You have to find which bus connected to your device. For that open your terminal and type:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
```

It will give you an output similar to:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0557 ProdID=2004 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=ATEN
S:  Product=UC100KM V2.00
```

In the above sample output, T has Bus with its ID. So, Bus id is 03.

or

To see Bus ID you can also use lsusb , open terminal & type:

```
lsusb
```

It will give you an output similar to:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0557:2004 ATEN UC100KM V2.00
```

Which means Bus ID 003.

You now know that the USB gets connected to BUS ID 003. Then in terminal type:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/3u > /tmp/1.mon.out
```

In the above command, you are monitoring the data transmission happening in Bus ID 03. If you want to monitor the data transmission at all Buses, then type:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u > /tmp/1.mon.out
```

Which will scan until the transmission goes to the end. If you want to interrupt then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

To understand the output read: [**The usbmon: USB monitoring framework**](http://people.redhat.com/zaitcev/linux/OLS05_zaitcev.pdf)

Comment: But that file 1.mon.out is showing very weird output , how to use that output to calculate the data transferred in Bytes ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b6U7Je7h

Comment: @user3529205 Found it. Please look at 2nd link in my answer.

Comment: still i think there is no way to find the size of packet file ?

Comment: do u think www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt#163 i what i need ?

Comment: @user3529205 yes , its explaining the output.

Comment: please can you point out in line 1-5 of pastebin link what would be the length field ? actually after " Number of isochronous frame descriptors and descriptors themselves" and before " < > = " signs there are two numbers

Answer (score 2):

Find the bus number your device is on (see shekar's answer). Then on the raw /dev/usbmonX, use **pipemeter** (or pipebench) to measure throughput, or dump it to a file and visualize its growth with **speedometer**..f.e. for device on bus number 2:

```
# next three commands are equivalent - use any one
# pipemeter /dev/usbmon2 > /dev/null
# pipemeter < /dev/usbmon2 > /dev/null
# cat /dev/usbmon2 | pipemeter > /dev/null

# in 1st terminal
# cat /dev/usbmon2 > /tmp/usbdump
# in 2nd terminal
# speedometer /tmp/usbdump
```

The formatted text output from the /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/Xu files produces overhead for small amounts of traffic but seems to truncate bigger data blocks, so the raw usbmon device should give you more exact figures.

Answer (score 2):

Install wireshark than easiest way is to:

1. Check device "Bus" and Number "Device" with lsusb ( in "" are lsusb fields)
2. Mount usbmon `sudo modprobe usbmon`
3. Start wireshark `sudo wireshark`
4. In wireshark select what to listen to: `usbmon{Bus nr form lsusb} fe: usbmon1`
5. Add filter for your "Device" number

Cleaner way is to add rule for usbmon for your user, than you can use it (and wireshark) without root privileges